# Electron SSLKEYLOGFILE decrypt TLS

Tags: networking, electron, reverse-engineering, wireshark

I have a question regarding Electron, since I have very limited understanding of the framework.

So what am I trying to achieve:
I am developing some sort of extension for an existing electron app, that exposes no API for my use case. The plan is to react on certain events that occure in the electron app. Those events are retrieved and transmitted via network. So my idea is to analyze the network traffic and wait for the relevant payloads.

Nearly everything is transmitted via TLS, why I am starting the electron app with environment variable "SSLKEYLOGFILE". That causes the app to write it's tls secrets into a file which can be analyzed by Wireshark. This works to some extend. I am able to decrypt a good portion of the traffic.

But there are also streams that originate from the electron app that cannot be decrypted because the secrets are not written to the log file. These streams also ignore when I start the app with "--proxy-server". So I suspect there is some kind of isolated part in the application that does not apply the provided configuration supplied to electron wrapper.

Do you have any hints for me how I can further investigate on this topic?

Comment: How do you know that the streams originate from the app? AFAIK, `SSLKEYLOGFILE` is a feature of OpenSSL, which would be used for any of the app's traffic. Also, I'd rather work with the original authors of the app to get a working API than to decrypt all the app's traffic, probably getting access to sensitive user information which clearly wasn't the original authors' intent since there's no API for that...

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I know since I can interact with the app and see reproducable the same tls packages (origin, destination, size) therefor i am pretty sure it is the payload that I am interested in. 

I am totally with you, I'd rather prefer to work with the author, but there is currently no opportunity to do this. So I am grateful for every hint to achieve this anyway.